# Getting runtime error C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve this problem from SPOJ
http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/

and here's my code
http://ideone.com/03Dd8u

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
typedef unsigned int ui;

using namespace std;

ui revNum(ui a)
{
   ui rev,tmp=a;
   while(tmp>0){
      rev=rev*10+(tmp%10);
      tmp=tmp/10;
   }
   return rev;
}

ui palin(ui k)
{
   ui num=k,rev=revNum(num);
   while(num!=rev){
      num++;
   }
   return num;
}

int main()
{
   ui t,out;
   vector<ui> k;
   cin>>t;
   for(ui i=0;i<t;i++){
      cin>>k[i];
      out=palin(k[i]);
      cout<<out<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

But I keep getting runtime error. Can someone identify the fault in my code?

Comment: You say 'runtime error', but what kind of runtime error? Segmentation fault? Doesn't your debugger tell you anything?

Comment: You need to either explicitly expand your vector `k`, or use `push_back` - you can't just assign to non-existent vector elements.

Comment: @ATaylor, we're his debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing an index in a vector that does not exist. The line:

```
cin>>k[i];
```

Is inserting into a vector with index i, but this index does not exist. The [] operator does not perform bounds checking.

Try changing the code to:

```
ui tmp;
cin >> tmp;
k.push_back(tmp);
```

As you see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at bounds checking is not performed.

Answer (score 2):

I can only see one glaring fault and that's at the line

```
cin >> k[i];
```

In this line, you seem to access an array element, however the array element doesn't exist yet. To add to a vector, please use the `push_back`-method like this:

```
ui in;
cin >> in;
k.push_back(in);
```

From that point on, you can access k[i], since the array element now exists.

Alternatively, just don't use a vector at all.

```
for(ui i=0;i<t;i++){
    ui in;
    cin >> in;
    out = palin(in);
    cout<<out<<endl;
}
```

See? No vector required.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
vector<ui> k;
   cin>>t;
   for(ui i=0;i<t;i++){
      cin>>k[i];
```

You never allocate any space in `k`.  For safety you can use `k.at(i)` which will throw an exception if the space doesn't exist.  Before the loop you can do `k.resize(t)`.